# Como retornar un componente usando onPress

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estoy implementando un filtro en mi proyecto de react native,para esto haria uso del evento onPress de un boton y este ejecutaria una funcion,pero me he dado cuenta que una funcion no me puede retornar componentes de texto o card

Los datos vienen de firebase por lo que se usa `.map()`

```
    <Button  title="Alquilar"  color='#B13682'   onPress={this.rojo()}  />

  rojo(){
  this.state.usuarios.map((user) => {
    if(user.Color=='Rojo'){
      return(
        <Card >
        <CardImage source={{uri: user.urlimg}}/>
      </Card>
     
      )
    }
  })
 }
```

Cuando hago uso de una constante dentro del render() y hago lo mismo del codigo de arriba,si se puede visualizar la card pero entonces no encuentro la forma de llamar esta constante mediante el evento `onPress`

```
render(){

const mostrar=
  this.state.usuarios.map((user) => {
    if(user.Color=='Rojo'){
      return(
        <Card >
        <CardImage source={{uri: user.urlimg}}/>
      </Card>
     
      )
    }
}) 

return(

 {mostrar} 
)
}
```

Como podria entonces hacer el llamado?o mejor opcion?
gracias,me serviria de ayuda para mi proyecto de grado

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que no podrás retornar mas de un componente.

Así que la función solo retornara un valor:

```
rojo(){
  let user=this.state.usuarios.find(usuario=>usuario.Color == "Color");
  return <Card >
             <CardImage source={{uri: user.urlimg}}/>
         </Card>
}
```

`find` es una funcion que devuelve el valor del primer elemento del `array` que cumple la función de prueba proporcionada. En este caso que el **color del usuario sea rojo**

Te recomiendo leer [array en javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)